# How to update an embedded document within an embedded document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am building an API in node.js which uses mongodb and mongoose. Currently I have an embedded document within an embedded document (Schema within a Schema) that is simply not persisted to the database, and I have tried all I can but no luck.

I have the Schema's defined in mongoose as:

```
var BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
  creationTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  author: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  title: { type: String },
  body: { type: String },
  comments: [CommentSchema]
});

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  creationTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  user: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  body: { type: String, default: "" },
  subComments: [SubCommentSchema]
});

var SubCommentSchema = new Schema({
  creationTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  user: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  body: { type: String, default: "" }
});
```

And the code I execute is as follows:

```
// Create a comment
app.post("/posts/:id/comments", function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.find({ _id : req.params.id }, function(err, item){
    if(err) return next("Error finding blog post.");                
    item[0].comments.push(new Comment(JSON.parse(req.body)));
    item[0].save(); // <= This actually saves and works fine
    respond(req, res, item[0].comments, next);
  });
});

// Create a subcomment
app.post("/posts/:id/comments/:commentid/subcomments", function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.find({ _id : req.params.id }, function(err, item){
    if(err) return next("Error finding blog post.");
    item[0].comments[req.params.commentid - 1].subcomments.push(new SubComment(JSON.parse(req.body)));
    item[0].save(); // <= This completes (without error btw) but does not persist to the database
    respond(req, res, item[0].comments[req.params.commentid - 1].subcomments, next);
  });
});
```

I can create Blog Posts with comments without problem, but for some reason I can not create subcomments on a comment. The Blog Post document actually has the comments and subcomments attached when printing to the console during execution - only it does not save to the database (it saves the Blog Post with a comment, but no subcomments).

I have tried to "markModified" on the comments array, but no change:

```
Posts.markModified("comments"); // <= no error, but also no change
...
Posts.comments.markModified("subcomments"); // <= produces an error: "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'markModified'"
```

Comment: I'm now thinking I may have to cast the object from MongoDB somehow? As it's maybe not recognizing the comment and subcomment as mongoose documents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem since solved. I was given the answer by Aaron Heckmann over on the [mongoose Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/0p-rhtcJdng):

> Always declare your child schemas before passing them to you parent schemas otherwise you are passing undefined.
>
> SubCommentSchema should be first, then Comment followed by BlogPost.

After reversing the schemas it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I thing the updating of a document is not an important issue as the embedded documents are also fully capable of any services.

Comment: Hmm, somewhat cryptic. Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to say?