# updating embedded sub documents - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following schemas:

```
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
comments     : String,
rating       : String,
submitted_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
numAgreed    : Number,
numDisagreed : Number
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName    : String,
    lastName     : String,
    numRatings   : Number,
    averageRating: Number,
    reviews      : [reviewSchema]
});
```

I am implementing an agree function (increment number of those who agreed with the review) for every review as follows:

```
exports.processAgree = function(req,res){
var firstName = req.body.firstName;
var lastName = req.body.lastName;
var index = req.body.index;

User.findOne({firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName}).lean().exec(function(err,user) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        user.reviews[index].numAgreed++;

        user.markModified('reviews');

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;

         });

    }

});
```

};

However, I get the error:

```
reviewedUser.markModified('reviews');
                     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'markModified'
```

I searched through stackoveflow and have seen responses to this issue but they don't to work in my case. E.g. There was a response at [How to update an embedded document within an embedded document in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402973/how-to-update-an-embedded-document-within-an-embedded-document-in-mongoose)

The solution suggests to declare child schemas before the parent schemas which is the case in my situation.

Please let me know if more information is required to help.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `lean()` from your `findOne` call chain. You need a full model instance if you want to save changes to the doc.

Answer (score 0):

As Johnny said, you should remove the call to lean method on Query.

Such that your code would look like

```
User.findOne({firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName}).exec(function(err,user) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        user.reviews[index].numAgreed++;

        user.markModified('reviews');

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    }
});
```

Lean is used to strip all the service methods and properties from objects that come from Mongoose methods. If you don't use `lean` method on Query object, Mongoose will return instances of Model. [Mongoose doc on lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean).

And `markModified` method, that you are looking for, resides in Mongoose Model instance. By the way, `save` is in Model instance too.